# What words are usually used to describe the units at middle level of a college?

Tags: word-usage

I only know the word "department", such as Foreign Languages Department, but I was told that in some colleges such units are also known as "school" or "college" (a college within a college). If it is a unit of research, it could also be named "center" or "institute". What are the proper words for such units at middle level of a college(or university)?

Comment: You've named all of the ones that I could think of.

Comment: There is extraordinary diversity in the ways academic institutions are organized in the Anglophone world, even among similar types of institutions within the same country. Terminology is not consistent; what one institution refers to as a *course* another may refer to as a *program* and what one organizes as a *division* another might consider a *faculty*. If you just want a survey of terminology, browse the "academic units" sections on the websites of institutions in the countries you're interested in.

Comment: @choster You are right. So now I get the whole picture, that is, there is no fixed word for that purpose and people can choose any word that they think fit. Is it the same for the professional titles of the teaching staff? Like in this country people call this one professor, that one lecturer, while in others they call this fellow, that rector, things like that?

Comment: @NanningYouth Yes, [academic ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_ranks) vary from country to country; a *lecturer* in the UK is a much more distinguished position than a *lecturer* in the US for example. Administrative titles vary from institution to institution, so the Chancellor of the College of William & Mary has a very different role from the Chancellor of the University of California, Los Angeles and from the Chancellor of the University of Alabama System.